# Icons / Symbols for Concepts or Learning Material

Tags: symbols

I am on a journey of creating high quality Material for Software-Development learners about the topic of how to write good or "Clean" code. I am currently searching for Symbols / Icons (not concrete ones) but more descriptions from UX Expterts like you what kind of a symbol would represent those concepts. I'll also outline what i have in mind so far:

1. **"Reducing Dependencies between Modules" and "Putting things where they Belong"**
   This Concept is actually about keeping things well ordered. Putting things where they belong, keeping things together that belong together and splitting things up that do not belong together because they don't share similarities.
2. **Readability** or **Accessability** this topic is about keeping the code readably for any programmer of any knowledge level. Keeping things as simple, clean and readable as possible, and also important omitting things that are not needed, overly complex or duplicated information. We could also say it's about "Preventing Brain Overload" and keeping things in consumable chunks.
3. **Focus on the initial Goals** or **Keeping functionality in mind** this topic convers the importance of "Doing the right things", of programming (only) what is needed to achieve the softwares designated goals and of not doing any work that "might be needed in the future" but has not yet been requested. It's about beeing creative about HOW to solve something but stop beeing creative about WHAT to solve.

So far i tried a search at the noun project and chatgpt. ChatGpts suggestions are more creative then i thought but hard to actually design. The noun project stuff is too "ambigous".

I have the hope to find symbols or pictures that can be easily connected with those topics once they are explained on a very high level like i explained here in the question. I am really trying to hit the nail on the head but i am lacking the experience and background in visual communication.

Comment: Hi Chris, icon suggestions are off-topic for this site. However, with this level of specificity, I think you're not looking for icons, but illustrations . Personally, I'd forget about any imagery and just make teh titles readable and clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have brainstormed some ideas for each topic.

> Reducing Dependencies between Modules" and "Putting things where they
> Belong

To me, this means having some type of order. The first thing that comes to mind is something that interlocks, an icon that shows objects connecting to create a bigger picture. I think a puzzle is pretty easy to recognize.

> Readability or Accessibility

The first thing that comes to mind is how browsers have "Reader View". I took this concept and added a magnifying glass to it. There is also a universally icon for Accessibility. So maybe that works for your project. Another idea is using a hierarchy icon to show order and clean code.

> Focus on the initial Goals or Keeping functionality in mind

The 2 words that stick out to me the most are "Goals" and "what is needed". So I created a checklist.

Example icons

[image: Icons]

Comment: Great Input thank you!